# How does one change the delay that occurs after entering an incorrect password?

Tags: login, pam, hardening

After entering an incorrect password at a login prompt, there s an approximately 3-second delay. How can I change that on a Linux system with PAM?

Comment: I get the need for a delay from a security perspective, but the default delay *is* rather annoying

Comment: This has been interesting; maybe I'll write a module that allows N tries with no delay followed by any number of tries with a long delay.

Comment: Instead of a new module (suggested in my previous comment), I used `pam_unix` with the `nodelay` option and `pam_tally2` with `deny=5 unlock_time=15`; this allows for 5 immediate retries, but denies access (even with a successful password) for 15 seconds. I still intend to try writing the described model, but now it's a back-burner project, because this would not be suitable if your primary access to the system is network-based since it makes a DOS attack trivial.

Comment: if you are concerned about a network DoS from timeouts, use fail2ban... in fact use it even if you think you're safe :-).  i use two day ban times

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I assume you are using Linux and pam. The delay is probably caused by [`pam_faildelay.so`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_faildelay). Check your pam configuration in `/etc/pam.d` using `pam_faildelay`, e.g:

```
# Enforce a minimal delay in case of failure (in microseconds).
# (Replaces the `FAIL_DELAY' setting from login.defs)
# Note that other modules may require another minimal delay. (for example,
# to disable any delay, you should add the nodelay option to pam_unix)
auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=3000000
```

To change the time adjust the delay parameter. If you want to get rid of the delay you can delete/comment the complete line.

Another source for the delay may be [`pam_unix.so`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_unix). To disable the delay caused by `pam_unix.so` add the `nodelay` parameter, and optionally add a line calling `pam_faildelay.so` to add a (variable) delay instead, e.g.:

```
auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=100000
```

Comment: There is no mention of delay anywhere in `/etc/pam.d/*`. The closest thing I see is `pam_tally.so` which allows locking after some number of attempts. But I do have n `/etc/login.defs`, which might be what I need.

Comment: @ShawnJ.Goff `pam_tally.so` does not cause an delay as far as i know. Another source for the dealy may be `pam_unix.so` - you can disable it with the `nodelay` option - see http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_unix for more details

Comment: Adding the `nodelay` option to `pam_unix.so` and adding a new entry with `pam_faildelay.so delay=$some_number` lets me set whatever I want. Thanks!

Comment: Running fedora 23, I had to disable the `pam_unix.so` delay and start using the `pam_faildelay.so` one as @ShawnJ.Goff says. However, most `pam.d` configs have "*This file is auto-generated. User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.*" So where can I permanently configure the delay?

Answer (score 13):

You need to pass the `nodelay` parameter to the `auth` `pam_unix.so`.

Depending on how your'e authenticating, where you need to set the parameter varies. However *most* linux distrubtions have something like `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` which is included by all the different files.

So for example in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` you might have a line that looks like this:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok
```

This should be changed to:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok nodelay
```

The `pam_unix.so` module is what performs authentication against `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. If youre using LDAP or some other password backend, you likely should still be setting `nodelay` on the `pam_unix.so` as that is what controls the prompt (when `pam_unix.so` fails to auth, it usually just passes the password it obtained to the next module).

You can read more about `pam_unix.so` by doing `man pam_unix`

Comment: On my system `system-auth` did not exist; it was `/etc/common-auth`. Thanks!