# Too big delay with xscreensaver on wrong password in OpenSUSE 12.2

Tags: login, opensuse, timeout, screen-lock, xscreensaver

There is too big delay when logging in with xscreensaver in OpenSUSE 12.2

--- Actual delay is 10 seconds, but not found anywhere in configs

Already done:

- checked pam timeout in *login.defs* (3 seconds)
- no pam_faildelay.so options in any of `/etc/pam.d/` files
- checked login settings via YaST (uses *login.defs* so useless)
- played with pam_faildelay.so delay parameter in `/etc/pam.d/login`, `/etc/pam.d/commom-auth-pc` files
- `.xscreensaver` config in `/home/`

```
    timeout:    0:10:00
    cycle:      0:10:00
    lock:       True
    lockTimeout:    0:00:00
    passwdTimeout:  0:00:05
    visualID:   default
    installColormap:    True
    verbose:    False
    timestamp:  True
    splash:     False
    splashDuration: 0:00:05
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It existed in 12.1 as well.

Comment: try to `strace` or `ltrace` it

Comment: `passwdTimeout:  0:00:05`?

Comment: I have the same problem with a timeout of about 20 seconds. With verbose output configured in .xscreensaver I observed that the command /sbin/unix2_chkpwd is called which takes about 10 seconds to return checking for the user password and another 10 seconds where it checks the password against the root password. I am using "slock" for now as an alternative to xscreensaver.

Answer (score 2):

The passwdTimeout (class Time) parameter determines the wait time between failed passwords.

from the man page:

> Options to xscreensaver are stored in one of two places: in a .xscreensaver file in your home directory; or  in the X resource database.  If the .xscreensaver file exists, it overrides any settings in the resource database.

The only conceivable error here is that the daemon is not running as your user. It could also be that there is a bug in the package for your distro, in which case you could build from source.

Comment: I've already played with passwdTimeout option from .xscreensaver

Comment: I know you have. I'm saying your program or the way it is executed is the issue. Setting that value has the desired effect with xscreensaver 5.15 on Gentoo.

Comment: `passwdTimeout` seems to indicate how much time you have to enter the password (setting it to lower numbers speeds up the vertical bar), not the delay on wrong password.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40954/13792