# Why is sudo slow when I mistype my password?

Tags: terminal, sudo

If I'm asked for the `sudo` password, after typing it in correctly, the terminal moves on almost instantaneously. However, if I mistype my password, it takes a few seconds before working it out and asking me again. I timed it a few times, and mostly takes around 2.2 seconds.

Why does it take so much longer, and is there a way to speed it up?

(I have a few dodgy keys on my [mechanical keyboard](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=25055) that often don't register, or register twice, so I often mistype my password.)

Comment: See: `pam_faildelay`.

Comment: @jordanm - thank you! That's exactly what I'm looking for to penalize the Chinese ssh password guessers.

Comment: @jordanm This looks related, but I can see in `/etc/login.defs` is the line `FAIL_DELAY 3`. My pause is always lower than that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there a big delay after entering a wrong password?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2126/80216) ... see also [How does one change the delay that occurs after entering an incorrect password?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40954/80216)

Comment: Thanks for the link @G-Man. I missed it somehow. Thanks for the second link, too; that was my follow-up question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in delay is to slow down the process of password guessing. Looks like someone could programmatically guess about 27 potential passwords per minute, which, as you've observed is a good deal less than if there was no delay.